# how to make content to be fixed inside scroll div using only css?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

As per shown in below image , I want blue div to be fixed at its place even after scroll "Hello World" div. I have tried it http://jsfiddle.net/9v6xwkk2/3/ but unable to get it. please help me and thanks in advance.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="inner">
<div class="full-height">
    Fix unscrollable content
</div>
    <div style="width:400px;height:400px;background:black:color:white">Hello World</div>

</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this -

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 256px;
    width: 256px;
}
.inner {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 16px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 256px;
    width: 100%;
}
.full-height {
    background: blue;
    bottom: 17px;
    color: white;
    left: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 238px;;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        <div style="width:400px;height:400px;background:black:color:white">Hello World</div>
    </div>
    <div class="full-height">
        Fix unscrollable content
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want footer to be fixed at the bottom, you can use `position:fixed` property.

http://jsfiddle.net/g65nn980/

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px red;
    height: 256px;
    width: 256px;
    overflow: auto;

    float: left;
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.inner {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.full-height {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
}

.full-height {
    position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    color:white;
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: I want footer inside scrollble div not outside

Comment: In your fiddle footer is already at bottom of inside the div (.inner). How did you want it?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
    * { box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px red;
    height: 256px;
    width: 256px;
    overflow: auto;

    float: left;
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.inner {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.full-height {
    position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    color:white;
    background: blue;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/9v6xwkk2/5/)